# Como cargar un JSON sin clave en una clase en FLUTTER

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Como puedo cargar en una clase el siguiente JSON?

JSON:

```
{
0: {
id: "24",
nombre: "Test",
desc:"EJEMPLO",
status:0
},
1: {
id: "26",
nombre: "Test 1",
desc:"EJEMPLO",
status:0
},
2: {
id: "27",
nombre: "Test 2",
desc:"EJEMPLO",
status:1
},  
error: 0,
}
```

Mi clase Productos:
(Solo necesito capturar esos 3 campos)

```
class Productos{
  final int id;
  final String nombre;
  final String desc

  Productos(this.id, this.nombre, this.desc);

  static Productos fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json){
    return Productos(
      id:json["id"],
      nombre:json["nombre"],
      desc:json["desc"],
    );
  }
}
```

Intente con algo como:
_prod=((json) as List).map((e) => Productos.fromJson(e)).toList();

pero no logre obtenerlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, aunque tienes algunos errores en el código que pusiste como el constructor de `Productos` , te faltaron las llaves para parámetros opcionales y el tipo de dato de id es String, según el json.

Este sería el código corregido:

**Data**

```dart
    final data = {
      0: {'id': "24", 'nombre': "Test", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 0},
      1: {'id': "26", 'nombre': "Test 1", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 0},
      2: {'id': "27", 'nombre': "Test 2", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 1},
      'error': 0,
    };
```

**Parsing**

```dart
    final products = data.keys.map((key) {
      if (key == 'error') {
        final error = data[key];
        if (error == 0) {
          print('no hay error');
        } else {
          print('error');
          throw Exception();
        }
      } else {
        return Productos.fromJson(data[key]);
      }

      return null;
    }).where((element) => element != null);
```

**Checking**

```dart
 for (Productos p in products) {
      print('P: ${p.id}, ${p.nombre}, ${p.desc}');
    }
```

**Clase corregida**

```dart
class Productos {
  final String id;
  final String nombre;
  final String desc;

  Productos({this.id, this.nombre, this.desc});

  static Productos fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Productos(
      id: json["id"],
      nombre: json["nombre"],
      desc: json["desc"],
    );
  }
}
```

En mi opinión, esos números/índices están de más, solo complican la estructura del json, podría retornar un array en lugar de eso.
Algo como :

```json
   {
      'data': [{'id': "24", 'nombre': "Test", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 0},
               {'id': "26", 'nombre': "Test 1", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 0},
               {'id': "27", 'nombre': "Test 2", 'desc': "EJEMPLO", 'status': 1}],
      'error': 0
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano @diegoveloper!
Me funciono de maravilla